# User Totals not matching row counts

Tags: google-analytics

Having a very strange issue with analytics which has only really appeared recently for no apparent reason.

I currently have User-Id set up on my view and it is recording a unique id for each user (have confirmed via page source and Google Tag Assistant). However, any report or widget I make that uses the Users metric only ever outputs the user count as 1. Even more vexing, the column total reflects a different number to the sum of all the rows

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in GA to me.   Are you still having this issue now that it is a couple months later?

Comment: On and off, but not noticed it since the latest GA update so can probably close this question

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate that this problem appears to be fixed in the latest version of Google Analytics.